# Legend entry for color and marker

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I have a plot which defines line properties based on test parameters.  For example, in the plot below, blue lines have a value of A=1, and red is A=2. The solid lines with dots have B=10 and dashed with Xs B=20.  When I create a legend, it makes an entry for each line plotted.  I would like to have a legend something like this:

[blue] A=1
[red] A=2
-. B=10
--x B=20

I have many more entries than what you see below, so this would save a lot of space.  Does anyone know if this is possible in Matlab?

[image: sample plot]

**UPDATE**

Here's what I've tried towards Eitan's answer, to no luck.

```
figure(2);
plot(1:5,1:5,'b');
hold all;
plot(1:5,1:5,'r');
plot(1:5,1:5,'k.-');
plot(1:5,1:5,'kx--');
h = get(gca,'Children');
M = {'A=1','A=2','B=10','B=20'};
figure(1);
legend(h,M); % This makes the legend appear in Figure 2, but I want it in 1.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way to do it would be first storing in an array `h` four handles corresponding to four sample lines in the following way:

- `h(1)` is the handle of a blue solid line.
- `h(2)` is the handle of a red solid line.
- `h(3)` is the handle of a dot-dash line.
- `h(4)` is the handle of a dot-cross line.

and then feeding them into `legend` alongside the desired strings like so:

```
legend(h, 'A = 1', 'A = 2', 'B = 10', 'B = 20')
```

*EDIT: If you cannot obtain these four handles, it is also possible to plot separately "empty" lines (having `NaN` values for their coordinates) that have the same graphical properties (blue, red,  dot-dash and cross-dash), and then get their handles. This way they exist as lineseries, but aren't actually plotted.*

Comment: I tried this, and I can only get the legend to appear in the figure associated with `h`, not in my original figure. I used `h(n) = plot(...);` to generate the handles.

Comment: Here h is not a figure handle, it's a vector of handles of the sample lineseries. How are you plotting those lines? Can you show sample code?

Comment: So then I should ask, how do you get that? I tried `h = get(gca,'Children')` on the sample lines, and that didn't work either.

Comment: This should indeed give you the vector of handles of all the lines, but you need only four, right? So you'll have to keep four handles from this vector, one for each type. For instance, if the first four lines are of the four different types indeed, you could use `h(1:4)`

Comment: I posted the code I used to attempt your solution, but I think I understand the problem. Your solution requires that the sample lines actually appear in the plot, where I was intending that they did not.

Comment: Found a way to make it work! I simply plotted the sample lines with y-value of `NaN`.  This way they appear as a Child for the legend, but don't actually show up on the plot!

Comment: @DavidK Ah, I didn't understand that you wanted the legend to appear in a different figure. You came up with a nice workaround, I'll revise my answer accordingly to make it complete.